# An error has ocurred. See the log file /User/workspace/.metadata/.log

Tags: java, macos, installation, workspace, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to install Eclipse Neon 3 in my MacBook with Mac Os X and in the installation process, after choose my workspace folder appears this message:

- An error has ocurred. See the log file /users/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.log

When I enter in the document using Terminal (nano /.metadata/.log) I don't understand anything. Someone can help me and give me an answer to this problem?

[This is the screenshot about /.metadata/.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABjft.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse won't run with Java 9 unless you modify the eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to this bug?
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493761

Seems to be a workaround to add vmarg:
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM